# How to get the value of slider which defined inside screen widget in kivy

Tags: python-3.x, slider, kivy, screen

I am making one kivy file and linking with python file. I defined slider inside screen in kivy and thought access inside the python. But getting error like this `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'`after running the below main.py file

Here is main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition

class Maintenance(Screen):
    pass
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
   pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("ex4.kv")

class ex4(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ex4, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
       return presentation
    def my_value(self):

        print(self.root.ids.slider1.value)



if __name__ == '__main__':
   ex4().run()
```

ex4.kv

```
#:import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition

ScreenManagement:
    transition:SlideTransition()

    Maintenance:
<Maintenance>:
    name: 'screen1'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Slider:
           id: slider1
           on_value:app.my_value()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id `slider1` belongs to the instance of `Maintenace` class. **An id is limited in scope to the rule it is declared in**, therefore, `ScreenManagement` instance has no id called `slider1`.

There are several ways to solve it, using properties for example, but I think the simplest thing is pass the slider's value to the callback as an argument:

**ex4.kv**

```
#:import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition

ScreenManagement:
    transition: SlideTransition()
    Maintenance:

<Maintenance>:
    name: 'screen1'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Slider:
            id: slider1
            on_value: app.my_value(self.value)  # <<<<<<<<<<<
```

**main.py:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition


class Maintenance(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


presentation = Builder.load_file("ex4.kv")


class Ex4(App):

    def build(self):
        return presentation

    def my_value(self, value):  # <<<<<<<<<<<
        print(value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Ex4().run()
```

Keep in mind that you do not need `builder.load_file`. If your `ex4.kv` is in the same directory as your `main.py`, just:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition


class Maintenance(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass



class Ex4(App):

    def my_value(self, value):
        print(value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Ex4().run()
```

Comment: #FJSevilla https://stackoverflow.com/users/7131499/fjsevilla Thank you so much problem has been solved!!!